# 'Could not interpret input' error with sns.barplot

Tags: python, seaborn

Basically I converted query result into dataframe and tried plotting it using seaborn but I get a value error

This is a snapshot of the dataframe

[image]

This is a snapshot of error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is that the column name is `testscore` while you are calling it as `x='Test Score'` when calling the seaborn barplot. Correct the name there and you should be able to proceed